# Error creating bean with controller. Facing issues with autowired and qualifier annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, qualifiers

I'm creating an application for booking doctors appointments. Here I got 7 classes in pojo class

Inside the package com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto I have 7 pojo classes :

```
com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto

Admin.java
Appointment.java
Availability.java
Doctor.java
Feedback.java
Patient.java
User.java
```

Here inside the Dao I got 5 Dao method interfaces and 5 Dao Repository interfaces

```
com.capg.bookmydoctor.dao


IAdminDao.java

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.capg.bookmydoctor.dao;

import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.Admin;

public interface IAdminDao {


        public Admin addAdmin(Admin admin);
        public Admin updateAdmin(Admin admin);
        public Admin removeAdmin(Admin admin);
        public Admin viewAdmin(Admin admin);

    }

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IAdminDaoRepository.java

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.capg.bookmydoctor.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.Admin;

@Repository("IAdminDao")
public interface IAdminRepository extends IAdminDao, JpaRepository<Admin, Integer>{

}
```

Here I'm embedding only one Dao Interface and one Dao Repository interface code to make question small. Rest of the Interfaces are similar.

```
IAppointmentDao.java
IAppointmentRepository.java

IDoctorDao.java
IDoctorRepository.java

IFeedbackDao.java
IFeedbackRepository.java

IPatientDao.java
IPatientRepository.java
```

Here inside the service package I got 5 Service method interfaces and 5 Service Implementation classes

I guess due to these service classes I'm getting error because my main class is unable to find the service class even though I have used @Autowired and @Qualifier annotation.

```
com.capg.bookmydoctor.service 

IAdminService.java

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.capg.bookmydoctor.service;

import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.Admin;

public interface IAdminService {


    public Admin addAdmin(Admin admin);
    public Admin updateAdmin(Admin admin);
    public Admin removeAdmin(Admin admin);
    public Admin viewAdmin(Admin admin);

    }

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IAdminServiceImpl.java

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.capg.bookmydoctor.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dao.IAdminRepository;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.Admin;

@Service("IAdminService")
public class IAdminServiceImpl implements  IAdminService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("IAdminRepository")
    IAdminRepository adminDao;

    @Override
    public Admin addAdmin(Admin admin) {
        return adminDao.addAdmin(admin);
    }

    @Override
    public Admin updateAdmin(Admin admin) {
        return adminDao.updateAdmin(admin);
    }

    @Override
    public Admin removeAdmin(Admin admin) {
        return adminDao.removeAdmin(admin);
    }

   @Override
    public Admin viewAdmin(Admin admin) {
        return adminDao.viewAdmin(admin);
    }

    }
```

Here I'm embedding only one service Implementation class code to make question small. Rest of the service Implementation classes are similar just variables and methods differ.

```
IAppointmentService.java
IAppointmentServiceImpl.java


IDoctorService.java
IDoctorServiceImpl.java

IFeedbackService.java
IFeedbackServiceImpl.java

IPatientService.java
IPatientServiceImpl.java
```

Here Inside the controller package I got one class

```
com.capg.bookmydoctor.controller

BookMyDoctorController.java

package com.capg.bookmydoctor.controller;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.Admin;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.Appointment;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.AvailabilityDates;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.Doctor;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.FeedBack;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.Patient;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.service.IAdminService;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.service.IAppointmentService;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.service.IDoctorService;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.service.IFeedbackService;
import com.capg.bookmydoctor.service.IPatientService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/doctor")
public class BookMyDoctorController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("IAdminService")
    IAdminService adminService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("IAppointmentService")
    IAppointmentService appointmentService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("IDoctorService")
    IDoctorService doctorService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("IFeedbackService")
    IFeedbackService feedbackService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("IPatientService")
    IPatientService patientService;

    @PostMapping("/admin")
    public Admin addAdmin(@RequestBody Admin admin) {
        return adminService.addAdmin(admin);
    }

    @PutMapping("/admin")
    public Admin updateAdmin(@RequestBody Admin admin) {
        return adminService.updateAdmin(admin);
   }

    @DeleteMapping("/admin")
    public Admin removeAdmin(@RequestBody Admin admin) {
        return adminService.removeAdmin(admin);
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public Admin viewAdmin(@RequestBody Admin admin) {
        return adminService.viewAdmin(admin);
     }

    @GetMapping("/appointment")
    public List<Appointment> getAllAppointments() {
        return appointmentService.getAllAppointments();
    }

    @GetMapping("/feedback/all")
    public List<FeedBack> getAllFeedback(@RequestBody Doctor doc) {
        return feedbackService.getAllFeedback(doc);
    }

    @PostMapping("/patient")
    public Patient addPatient(@RequestBody Patient bean) {
        return patientService.addPatient(bean);
    }

    @PutMapping("/patient")
    public Patient editPatientProfile(@RequestBody Patient bean) {
        return patientService.editPatientProfile(bean);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/patient")
    public Patient removePatientDetails(@RequestBody Patient bean) {
        return patientService.removePatientDetails(bean);
    }

    @GetMapping("/patient")
    public Patient getPatient(@RequestBody Patient patient) {
        return patientService.getPatient(patient);
    }

    @GetMapping("/patient/all")
    public List<Patient> getAllPatient() {
        return patientService.getAllPatient();
    }

    @GetMapping("/patient/doctor")
    public List<Patient> getPatientListByDoctor(@RequestBody Doctor doctor) {
        return patientService.getPatientListByDoctor(doctor);
    }

    @GetMapping("/patient/{appdate}")
    public List<Patient> getPatientListByDate(@PathVariable LocalDate appdate) {
        return patientService.getPatientListByDate(appdate);
    }
```

Here inside the package com.capg.bookmydoctor I got spring booth application class

```
com.capg.bookmydoctor 

package com.capg.bookmydoctor;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.capg.bookmydoctor.controller,com.capg.bookmydoctor.dao,com.capg.bookmydoctor.service,com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto")
public class BookMyDoctorAppApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(BookMyDoctorAppApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

Here I have used same package name "com.capg.bookmydoctor" for all packages.

Here I have used @Service Annotation for all Service Implementation classes and specified service interface name in it.

I have used @Qualifier annotation with @Autowired since I got different Respositories and Service Implementation classes.

Inspite of doing all this I'm getting these errors in console

Errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookMyDoctorController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'adminService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'IAdminService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'adminDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.capg.bookmydoctor.dao.IAdminRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=IAdminRepository)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at com.capg.bookmydoctor.BookMyDoctorAppApplication.main(BookMyDoctorAppApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'IAdminService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'adminDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.capg.bookmydoctor.dao.IAdminRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=IAdminRepository)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
... 21 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.capg.bookmydoctor.dao.IAdminRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=IAdminRepository)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
... 35 common frames omitted
```

Please Help me to get rid of these errors

Thank you...

Comment: Your code used `@Qualifier`, but doesn't know why does it need it? :) You need `@Qualifier` when one Interface has many implementations and you inject one of those using `@Qualifier`. There is no need of `@Qualifier` in your code.

Comment: I have removed qualifiers even after that Im getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `IAdminRepository`, the name of the bean is `"IAdminDao"`.

```java
package com.capg.bookmydoctor.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.capg.bookmydoctor.dto.Admin;

@Repository("IAdminDao")
public interface IAdminRepository extends IAdminDao, JpaRepository<Admin, Integer>{

}
```

In the service class `IAdminServiceImpl`, you're autowiring with wrong `Qualifier`:

```java
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("IAdminRepository")
    IAdminRepository adminDao;
```

It should be:

```java
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("IAdminDao")
    IAdminRepository adminDao;
```

You should check for this in other DAO/Service classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have used annotations wrong all along. If you pass name to annotation like @Repository("IAdminDao") then you are creating bean of name “IAdminDao” which should be autowired by using @Autowire @Qualifier(IAdminDao) but what you are doing is @Qualifier("IAdminRepository") as there is no bean with this name, you’re getting error.

Remove all qualifiers if an interface has only single implementation and remove names from annotations used on interface/classes eg. write @Repository, @Service only. Then used @Autowired. This should start your application if bean dependency’s is the only issue. Or use bean naming as described in spring docs.